# Writing Junit5 test cases for List<List<Integer>> type

Tags: java, junit, junit5

Does JUNIT 5 provides any inbuilt assertions for testing an output which has type `List<List<Integer>>` 
 Or One needs to loop over it and compare each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the normal `assertEquals()` method to compare these objects. The `List<>` interface defines the [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method (which is used by `assertEquals()` as follow:

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements `e1` and `e2` are *equal* if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`.) In other words, two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. This definition ensures that the `equals` method works properly across different implementations of the `List` interface.